# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') while using <Button/> from ant design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I´m trying to use a Button from Ant Design, but I keep getting the error:

```bash
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at Object.useContext (http://localhost:3000/main.19e2674394eb4e9a7d19.hot-update.js:36279:25)
    at InternalButton (http://localhost:3000/main.19e2674394eb4e9a7d19.hot-update.js:4513:42)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:21088:22)
    at updateForwardRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23659:24)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25706:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:10680:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:10724:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:10781:35)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30655:11)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29902:16)
```

I´m using this code and trying to create a simple button but it does not work!

App.js:

```bash
import { Button } from 'antd';
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Teste</h1>
      <Button></Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```bash
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
// importando o CSS do Ant
import 'antd/dist/reset.css';

// importando o App
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Is that the only code in your app? 
Does removing the `Button` make the error stop?

Comment: Also, what version of `react` and `antd` are you using? (you can check your package.json)

This error looks like something you'd get when trying to use `React.useContext` but for some reason you couldn't import `React` properly. If you're not using `useContext` anywhere in your app, I'm guessing this might happen somewhere in the sourcecode of the `antd` lib. Maybe if there's some version conflict or something that would interfere with the React import there. (The stacktrace does indicate it's coming from the `InternalButton` component in `antd`)